# Can't Use Gradle With Cron Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, cron, vps

I have this report, but i can't understand why it doesn't recognize gradle command... I'm new to cron, thanks for your help!

```
From ubuntu@vps-a29e040b.vps.ovh.net  Sun Dec 13 04:02:01 2020
Return-Path: <ubuntu@vps-a29e040b.vps.ovh.net>
X-Original-To: ubuntu
Delivered-To: ubuntu@vps-a29e040b.vps.ovh.net
Received: by vps-a29e040b.vps.ovh.net (Postfix, from userid 1000)
    id EF0278157A; Sun, 13 Dec 2020 04:02:01 +0000 (UTC)
From: root@vps-a29e040b.vps.ovh.net (Cron Daemon)
To: ubuntu@vps-a29e040b.vps.ovh.net
Subject: Cron <ubuntu@vps-a29e040b> ./myscript.sh
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit
X-Cron-Env: <PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin>
X-Cron-Env: <SHELL=/bin/sh>
X-Cron-Env: <HOME=/home/ubuntu>
X-Cron-Env: <LOGNAME=ubuntu>
Message-Id: <20201213040201.EF0278157A@vps-a29e040b.vps.ovh.net>
Date: Sun, 13 Dec 2020 04:02:01 +0000 (UTC)

TERM environment variable not set.
./myscript.sh: line 4: gradle: command not found
```

Comment: The message is telling you that the `gradle` command you're trying to run is not located in the path that `cron` is using. Try changing your script to use the full path to `gradle`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`cron` is fairly easy to use, but it has some idiosyncrasies you should be aware of. Here's a brief summary:

#### 1. `cron` jobs have a different ENVIRONMENT

`cron` jobs run with an ENVIRONMENT that's different than your *interactive shell*. The PATH is part of the ENVIRONMENT. This may be the cause of your issue: the PATH to `gradle` may not be in the the PATH used by `cron`. This can cause issues for any `cron` job.

Solution: Typically this may be resolved by using a full path specification for all commands.
Instead of this:

```
0 2 * * * gradle
```

Use this:

```
0 2 * * * /full/path/to/gradle
```

#### 2. `cron` has no awareness of resource availability

`cron` does not verify that the resources needed to run a job are available before attempting to run the job. This is typically encountered in running a `cron` job at boot time (i.e. using the `@reboot` facility). An example of this situation is a job that runs at boot time & requires access to network resources.

Solution: This is typically resolved by adding a `sleep X` command prior to the job:

```
@reboot ( /bin/sleep 30; /home/myhome/myprog.sh )
```

#### 3. Runtime errors in a `cron` job are not reported

`cron` has no access to your terminal, so `stderr` goes to `/dev/null`. If you want to see errors (and you always do!), you need only to redirect `stderr` to a file - this is one way to do that:

```
0 2 * * * /home/myhome/dosomething.sh > /home/myhome/cronjoblog 2>&1
```

This redirects all `stdout` (1) to `/home/myhome/cronjoblog`, and redirects `stderr` (2) to `stdout` (2>&1). All output goes to your `cronjoblog` file.

[Further reading on `cron`](https://github.com/seamusdemora/PiFormulae/blob/master/MyCrontabDoesntWork.md)